# Swivel: training data with human judgement

Tags: tensorflow, word2vec

I was trying out swivel.py from the source: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.7/tensorflow/models/embedding/README.md

At the moment, it creates its own vocab from the text file that I ingest and trains itself.
However, the result is not much accurate since it generates its own relationship only by the number of times it occurs next to a target word.
For example, I have ingested information regarding drone, and on nearest.py my specified word was 'system'.
I was expecting the word 'drone' to pop out as one of the top on the list since the word drone is always next to the word system.
But it did not give out the expected result.

Is there any method or idea how to train the model by ingesting an already-trained data, so that it will be trained not by itself but with the help of human judgement?